# Apache CXF - Request Bean error

Tags: java, json, rest, xsd, cxf

I am trying to validate the incoming jsons by xsds. I had several services exposed and every service had different JSON each mapped to different POJOs.  So i wrote a master xsd which would contain all root elements of JSONs as sub elements and will import the respective xsds.

Now the problem is that I always get this exception:

```
WARNING: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'RequestBean'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement
```

My xsd is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/RequestBean"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/RequestBean" elementFormDefault="unqualified"
    xmlns:poi="http://www.example.org/PoiRequest" xmlns:sendcar="http://www.example.org/SendCar">
 <xs:import namespace="http://www.example.org/PoiRequest"
            schemaLocation="PoiRequest.xsd"/>
 <xs:import namespace="http://www.example.org/SendCar"
            schemaLocation="SendCar.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="RequestBean">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="PoiRequest" type="poi:PoiRequest" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="SendCar" type="sendcar:SendCar" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

My config is below:

```
<jaxrs:server id="restContainer" address="/">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="PoiSearch" />
            <ref bean="SendCar" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider">
            <property name="dropRootElement" value="true" /> 
            <property name="supportUnwrapped" value="true" />                               </bean>
        </jaxrs:providers> 
        <jaxrs:schemaLocations>
        <jaxrs:schemaLocation>file:C:\Desktop\xsds\RequestBean.xsd</jaxrs:schemaLocation>       <jaxrs:schemaLocation>file:C:\Desktop\xsds\PoiRequest.xsd</jaxrs:schemaLocation>
    <jaxrs:schemaLocation>file:C:\Desktop\xsds\Route.xsd</jaxrs:schemaLocation>
    <jaxrs:schemaLocation>file:C:\Desktop\xsds\Poi.xsd</jaxrs:schemaLocation>
    <jaxrs:schemaLocation>file:C:\Desktop\xsds\SendCar.xsd</jaxrs:schemaLocation> 

        </jaxrs:schemaLocations>
    </jaxrs:server>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first thing to check is the namespace or your XML document element. Your error points to an unqualified name, whereas your XSD uses a target namespace for RequestBean.

Comment: yeah it was regarding targetNamespace only, i am new to this whole xml schema. But after some hit and trial, i removed this attribute and voila it worked.